# Attemt to use SBT from Domino Java Agent fails with NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/http/protocol/BasicHttpContext.<init>()V

Tags: lotus-notes, javaagents, ibm-sbt

UPDATE OCT 30th, see at bottom of question.

I have created a working sample of a standalone java application in Eclipse (based on the SBT's sbt.sample.app GetAllCommunitiesApp.java. My only change is that I manually create my BasicEndpoint to skip the use of the managed beans for endpoint configuration (and thus the reading of managed-beans.xml). As said, this all works beautifully in Eclipse.

Moving the code to a local Notes Java agent (agent being placed in local database), I have first and foremost copied the SBT jar files to my C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Lotus\Notes\jvm\lib\ext catalog. See below for a list of these files. When I run the java agent, I get the following stack trace;

> 

```
Exception in thread "AgentThread: JavaAgent" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/http/protocol/BasicHttpContext.<init>()V
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.createHttpContext(AbstractHttpClient.java:285)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:851)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.executeRequest(ClientService.java:1043)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService._xhr(ClientService.java:1006)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.execRequest(ClientService.java:972)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.xhr(ClientService.java:932)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.get(ClientService.java:808)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.get(ClientService.java:804)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.base.BaseService.retrieveData(BaseService.java:350)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.base.BaseService.retrieveData(BaseService.java:372)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.base.BaseService.retrieveData(BaseService.java:325)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.base.BaseService.getEntities(BaseService.java:185)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.communities.CommunityService.getMyCommunities(CommunityService.java:265)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.communities.CommunityService.getMyCommunities(CommunityService.java:249)
    at no.tine.sbt.SBTCommunityHelper.getMyCommunities(SBTCommunityHelper.java:36)
    at JavaAgent.NotesMain(JavaAgent.java:27)
    at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Searching StackOverflow and other sites shows that others has seen similar problems with mixed versions of Apache's HttpClient (typically people has been using httpclient 4.0.1, and the problem went away replacing it with httpclient 4.1). 
The SBT includes httpclient-4.2.1.jar is that file is what I have copied to Lotus Notes's C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Lotus\Notes\jvm\lib\ext.

To me it seems like Lotus Notes somehow is using some other httpclient from somewhere, which perhaps is outdated.

So the question is - can I force Notes to use the SBT jars in some way? Any ideas?

For reference, the SBT jar files I copied to my C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Lotus\Notes\jvm\lib\ext are;

```
com.ibm.commons-1.0.0.20131024-1349.jar
com.ibm.commons.runtime-1.0.0.20131024-1349.jar
com.ibm.commons.xml-1.0.0.20131024-1349.jar
com.ibm.sbt.core-1.0.0.20131024-1349.jar
com.ibm.sbt.playground-1.0.0.20131024-1349.jar
apache-mime4j-0.6.jar
com.ibm.sbt.javamail-1.4.5.jar
commons-codec-1.3.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
httpclient-4.2.1.jar
httpcore-4.2.1.jar
httpmime-4.2.1.jar
```

UPDATE OCT 30th, 2013 - Found a sample which perhaps goes along the same lines. The following code is a complete Notes Java Agent, with core code directly from Apache.org HttpClient 4.2 example code. This too generates NoSuchMethodError, and is perhaps easier to debug than SBT.

```
 /*
 * Sample retrieved from 
 * http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.2.x/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientWithResponseHandler.java
 */
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import lotus.domino.*;

public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {

    public void NotesMain() {

      try {
          Session session = getSession();
          AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();

          HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
          try {
              HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com/");

              System.out.println("executing request " + httpget.getURI());

              // Create a response handler
              ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
              String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
              System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
              System.out.println(responseBody);
              System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

          } finally {
              // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
              // shut down the connection manager to ensure
              // immediate deallocation of all system resources
              httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
          }


          // Notes Exception catcher
      } catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: BTW; I just tried to replace the httpclient, httpcore etc with the files from SBT's com.ibm.sbt.libs.domino\lib-catalog. Unfortunately the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, where is your agent running from? 
Notes ? then that's a great location 
or On the Server? If on the server, you should make sure the libraries are there too.

One great test is to put the libraries in the Agent's code.

Open your Database in Designer

Expand the Database > Code > Agents

Open your Agent

Click on Archive

Click Import > Archive

Click Browse (Find the folder with the referenced jars)

Select the Jars you want

Click Finish

Click Save (let it compile)

Close and test

If that works, it's down to path issues

---- Updated ----

I added com.ibm.sbt.core / com.ibm.commons.xml com.ibm.commons.runtime com.ibm.commons httpcore httpclient commons-logging jars to the agent as an archive

I used your code, and changed the workspace compatibility to Java1.5

I then changed the Security to Level 3. ... you should try the same, and if it fails, you should look into conflicting java classes.

```
import lotus.domino.AgentBase;
import lotus.domino.AgentContext;
import lotus.domino.Session;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;



public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {

    public void NotesMain() {

        try {
            Session session = getSession();
            AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();
            lotus.domino.Log log = session.createLog("SampleAgentSBT");
            log.openAgentLog();

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            try {
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com/");

                log.logAction("executing request " + httpget.getURI());

                // Create a response handler
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget,
                        responseHandler);
                log.logAction("----------------------------------------");
                log.logAction(responseBody);
                log.logAction("----------------------------------------");

            } finally {
                // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
                // shut down the connection manager to ensure
                // immediate deallocation of all system resources
                httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            }
            log.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Paul and thanks for the reply. The agent runs from Lotus Notes client and the java agent is placed inside a local database. No server involved yet.

And yes, I have also tried to include all the mentioned jars directly in the Java agent. Additionally I have tried to include the jars in the Java Script library I have placed the code in. I have also tried to place the java files inside the agent.

So far, the stack trace for all variants. It seems like the Notes JVM prefer it's own version of httpclient/httpcore jar files somehow.

Comment: Another result from search. I do see that my Notes 9 Designer client have the following version of httpcore 4.0.1 installed;
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Lotus\Notes\osgi\shared\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.wink_1.1.2.20130301-1506\lib\httpcore-4.0.1.jar"
and
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Lotus\Notes\framework\shared\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.wink_1.1.2.20130301-1506\lib\httpcore-4.0.1.jar"

Now I am not sure whether these files ever comes to play in Notes client agent manager JVM or not. Just for the fun of it, I have tried to replace the 4.0.1 folder content with the content of SBT's 4.2.1.

Comment: did you change the restrictions on running the agent?

Comment: Paul, yes, I have also tried to elevate the agent security to 3 (= "Allow restricted operations ...").

Comment: Paul, THANK YOU VERY MUCH for taking your time to test. Just by having someone testing the code, and confirm that it actually work is so valuable. That means that I just have to hunt down the problem until it goes away. In my case it turned out that I had some issue with the standard jar files that was there. I took out every one, and for each restart of Notes, paied attention to what jar Designer was reporting missing. By doing this, it started to work!! I guess the reason has been some old and cached sequence which my current code didn't like too much. Fixing the order was the trick.